# Среда разработки GUI приложений в среде Linux язык C#

Tags: c#, linux

Хотелось бы выбрать оптимальную среду разработки GUI приложений в среде Linux язык C#. Я видел, что тема уже поднималась 9 лет назад и говорилось о  MonoDevelop, QT Creator, KDevelop, Eclipse. Но может, что-то еще новое появилось? И возможно ли установить их в Astra Linux CE / SE ?

Comment: 1) MonoDevelop 2) Visual Studio Code(не совсем IDE, но работать можно). 3) Rider(платный)

Comment: Вообще если нет цели перебираться на linux полностью и не собираетесь использовать GtkSharp, то в текущей ситуации лучше сидеть в студии.

Comment: Нет, как раз есть цель - перебраться на Linux полностью.